# Linux Kernel Module for firewall

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to block all traffic on all ports except for 443 and 80 for tcp and udp.  Udp works fine but tcp is just blocked completely, what did I do wrong here?

I tried the tcp on it's own and the code for tcp does not work and I am not entirely sure why.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>

static struct nf_hook_ops *nfho = NULL;

static unsigned int hfunc(void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct udphdr *udph;
    struct tcphdr *tcph;

    if (!skb) {
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    }
    iph = ip_hdr(skb);
    if (iph->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
        udph = udp_hdr(skb);
        if (ntohs(udph->dest) == 443 || (ntohs(udph->dest) == 80) {
            return NF_ACCEPT;
        }
    }
    else if (iph->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP) {
        tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);
        if (ntohs(tcph->dest) == 443 || (ntohs(tcph->dest) == 80) {
            return NF_ACCEPT;
        }
    }
    return NF_DROP;
}

static int __init LKM_init(void)
{
    nfho = (struct nf_hook_ops*)kcalloc(1, sizeof(struct nf_hook_ops), GFP_KERNEL);
    
    /* Initialize netfilter hook */
    nfho->hook  = (nf_hookfn*)hfunc;        /* hook function */
    nfho->hooknum   = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;      /* received packets */
    nfho->pf    = PF_INET;          /* IPv4 */
    nfho->priority  = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;      /* max hook priority */
    
    nf_register_net_hook(&init_net, nfho);
}

static void __exit LKM_exit(void)
{
    nf_unregister_net_hook(&init_net, nfho);
    kfree(nfho);
}

module_init(LKM_init);
module_exit(LKM_exit);
```

Comment: This would only accept incoming or outgoing packets to ports 80 or 443, but would not allow replies to those packets. So a TCP handshake is impossible, but UDP replies are impossible too. You probably need connection tracking here.

Comment: Why are you doing this with a kernel module instead of just using the built-in IP filtering of Linux?

Comment: I have to for a class, I wish I could do it a normal way lol.